# Wpf Data entry Form bound to datatable

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datatable

I was trying my hand on binding in Wpf.I am trying to make a dataenrty screen.for instance,I have a textbox and a combobox and a listview.. users enter pick an item from the combobox,add a comment and add the item to the listview.This is the flow.I have a master table for the combobox,i have its selectedvalue bound to a Item field in the ordertable and the textbox.text bound to comments field in order table.fine up to now.

from here on i'm confused,should i bind the lsitview to the order table?.If yes then how will i create a new row in the datatable each time add row is clicked..?

if a new row is created in the datatable,next time the user selects an item it should be bind to the newly created row...how can i do this...pls help...i'm pulling my hairs on this...

Comment: how you want to bind the table to list? are you using LINQ to SQL, Entity Framework or ADO.net dataset?

Comment: No Helps...I need info abt binding a listview to a generic dataset..

Answer (score 0):

you can see this

http://dotnetstories.wordpress.com/2009/03/28/create-a-simple-data-centric-wpf-application/